# Network statistics on Nexus 7

Tags: android, nexus-7

I want to read the network statistics on my Nexus 7 from the file system. On all devices tested before, the network statistics (e.g., tx_packets) were always located in

```
/sys/devices/virtual/net/wlan
```

However, although on the Nexus 7 there are four matching sub directories

```
/sys/devices/virtual/net/dummy
/sys/devices/virtual/net/ip6tnl0
/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo
/sys/devices/virtual/net/sit0
```

none of them seems to provide the right statistics, as all their statistic files do not change during Web access via WiFi.

Any sugestions where I might look as well?

Comment: did you find the answer to your query.. actually i am also facing the same issue...I am also not able to find the wlan0 folder inside the 
/sys/devices/virtual/net/.....

Comment: No, not yet. I assume that the information is simply not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the directory: /sys/class/net/*iface*/statistics/tx_packets

Example for *wlan0*

```
long txPackets= 0; //tx Packets
String cmd="cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/tx_packets\n";
Process p=null;
BufferedReader in2=null;

try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    txPackets= Long.parseLong(in2.readLine());  
}catch (Exception e)
{
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```